# 404 Error from XML calling Django function

Tags: python, html, django, xml

My django code takes a set of questions with 4 answers, 1 is correct, from a model. If the user clicks on the correct one, it should use javascript and XML to call a Django function which verifies whether it was the correct button, and give back a new colour and message and so on.

```
<button class="button questionbutton" id="3" style="vertical-align:middle; margin:35px 70px;" onclick="window.location.reload(true)"><span>{{ question.question3 }}</span></button>
            <button class="button questionbutton" id="4" style="vertical-align:middle; margin:35px 70px;" onclick="window.location.reload(true)"><span>{{ question.question4 }}</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.questionbutton');
        buttons.forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                const clicked = event.target;
                const selected = clicked.getAttribute('data');
                const check = clicked.getAttribute('correct') === 'true';
                const questionId = clicked.getAttribute('question');
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', '/processLB/', true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
                xhr.onload = function () {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        if (response.result === 'correct') {
                            if (check) {5
                                clicked.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                            } else {
                                clicked.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                            }
                        } else {
                            clicked.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                };
                xhr.send('selected=' + encodeURIComponent(selected) + '&question_id=' + encodeURIComponent(questionId));
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Is my HTML and javascript function. The problem is I am getting a 404 error stating that processLB() can't be found when clicking the button. I've run some tests and the whole thing works up until

```
xhr.onload = function () {
```

where the error happens. For reference my urls.py has the processLB function correctly formatted and that's not the problem. The function is in views.py and looks like this:

```
def processLB(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected = request.POST.get('selected')
        question = request.POST.get('question')
        try:
            questiondata = LearnBeginner.objects.get(pk=id)
            
            if selected == questiondata.correct:
                return JsonResponse({'result': 'correct', 'message': 'Correct!', 'response': {{questiondata.response}}}, status=200)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'result': 'incorrect', 'message': 'Incorrect!', 'response': {{questiondata.response}}}, status=400)
        except LearnBeginner.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'result': 'error', 'message': 'Question not found!'}, status=400)

    return JsonResponse({'result': 'error', 'message': 'Invalid request!'}, status=400)
```

Why am I getting the 404 error? This is my second ever Django project so I'm slightly unsure.